# How does the return type of the put method works in Hashtable or HashMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

In the documentations, the return type for the HashMap or Hashtable is the value itself as following,

```
public V put(K key, V value)
```

and, it tells about the return type is *the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)*

Say, if I write a Hashtable as following,

```
    Hashtable<Integer, Character> hash = new Hashtable<Integer, Character>();
    System.out.println(hash.put(12, 'c'));
```

Now, the above code returns `null`. I'm implementing a Hashtable and I'm slightly confused when to return null or V where V will be the previous value associated with key. My code is as following,

```
// for dealing w/ the table data
class HashEntry<K, V> {

    private final K key;
    private V value;


    public HashEntry(K key, V value) {

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey() {

        return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {

        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {

        this.value = value;
    }
 } 


class MyHashTable <K, V> {


private int size;
private int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;

private HashEntry<K, V>[] values = new HashEntry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];


public V put(K key, V value) {

    boolean insert = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (values[i].getKey().equals(key)) {

            values[i].setValue(value);
            insert = false;
        }

    }

    if (insert) {

        // method for check or increase capacity
        increaseCapacity();
        values[size++] = new HashEntry<K, V>(key, value);
    }

   return null;
   // return value; 
}
```

When should I return null or value ( type V) in the implementation ?

Comment: What do you not understand about it? The explanation in the documentation seems straightforward.

Comment: What's unclear? That behavior is specifically described in detail in the very docs you just quoted.

Comment: I edited the question and it's about Hashtable implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example this is your first time assigning a value to the key 12 so as stated in the documentation null is returned since there was no previous value stored for that key.

If you then did:

```
System.out.println(hash.put(12, 'd'));
```

'c' would be printed because it is returned as the previous value for the key 12.

**Edit based on additional info in question:**

Here is a possible implementation of your put method to return the previous value correctly.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    boolean insert = true;
    V prevValue = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (values[i].getKey().equals(key)) {
            prevValue = values[i].getValue();
            values[i].setValue(value);
            insert = false;
        }
    }

    if (insert) {
        // method for check or increase capacity
        increaseCapacity();
        values[size++] = new HashEntry<K, V>(key, value);
    }

    return prevValue;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I understand it. If any value previously associated w/ that key, that value will be returned.

Comment: Yes, it did now, you know there is a time duration and you can accept an answer only afterwards.